# Formula R1C1 Macro Erro 1004

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Tenho uma macro para aplicar uma fórmula em algumas células. Para conseguir ter a fórmula em formato VBA eu gravei a macro para gerar ela, porém quando fui rodar a macro ela roda o erro 1004...

```
U        Selection.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(AND(RC5=Infos!R2C4,RC9='Premissas Financeiras'!R6C2,RC3='Premissas Financeiras'!R2C3),(-RC16*'Premissas Financeiras'!R6C3), IF(AND(RC5=Infos!R2C4,RC9='Premissas Financeiras'!R7C2,RC3='Premissas Financeiras'!R2C3),(-RC16*'Premissas Financeiras'!R7C3), IF(AND(RC5=Infos!R2C4,RC9='Premissas Financeiras'!R6C2,RC3='Premissas Financeiras'!R2C4),(-RC16*'Premissas Financ" & _
        "6C4), IF(AND(RC5=Infos!R2C4,RC9='Premissas Financeiras'!R7C2,RC3='Premissas Financeiras'!R2C4),(-RC16*'Premissas Financeiras'!R7C4), IF(AND(RC5=Infos!R2C4,RC9='Premissas Financeiras'!R6C2,RC3='Premissas Financeiras'!R2C5),(-RC16*'Premissas Financeiras'!R6C5), IF(AND(RC5=Infos!R2C4,RC9='Premissas Financeiras'!R7C2,RC3='Premissas Financeiras'!R2C5),(-RC16*'Premissas F" & _
        "s'!R7C5),))))))"
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar! Não sei o que fazer mais, pois o range está definido. Obrigada

Comment: Ines, Seja bem vinda ao Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/407611/edit) e traduza a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Copie a fórmula do jeito que ela está na planilha.
Exemplo:

```
Range("C1").Formula = "=A1+B1"
```

Note que está sem o R1C1

Comment: O uso de `FormulaR1C1` está correto, já que a notação `A1` não está sendo utilizada, mas sim a referência relativa da notação `R1C1`. Mas creio que o jeito de realizar isto conforme a sua resposta é o mais fácil mesmo.